# Create intance of any C# class by generic way

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create an instance of any class using generics.
Is that possible?

I tried this but doesnt work:

```
public class blabla 
{
    public void bla();
}
public class Foo<T>
{
    Dictionary<string, Func<object>> factory;

    public Foo() => factory = new Dictionary<string, Func<object>>();
    public WrapMe(string key) => factory.Add(key, () => new T());
}

...

var foo = new Foo<blabla>();
foo.Wrapme("myBlabla");

var instance = foo.factory["myBlabla"];
instance.Bla();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a method:

```
private static T InstantiateInstance<T>() where T : new() => new T();
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to solve this:

**Variant 1**: Add `where T : new()` to your class definition:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : new()
{
    ...
}
```

For further details, see the description of [the **new()** constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

---

**Variant 2**: Pass the lambda `() => new T()` as a parameter to your constructor, store it in a `Func<T>` field and use it in `WrapMe`.

For further details, see [this blog post](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2007/11/an-alternative-to-the-c-generic-new-constraint/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`.

Comment: Yes, better than my approach.

Comment: @grenade - identical to your approach. The only difference is- your approach will fail at compile time, Diego's approach will fail at run time

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic, care to elaborate? Both approaches compile and run fine here.

Comment: if you don't add new() and use explicit call to Activator, the call will fail when you pass a type w/o default .ctor, that's the failing part.

When you add new() contstraint, and then call `var t = new T()` the compiler will emit the call to Activator.CreateInstance<T>(), that's the 'same' part.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [Inversion of Control container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx), like [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new constraint when declaring Foo. This only works for types with a constructor with no arguments - which is fine in your case.