# C# Derive From Generic Base Class (T : U<T>)

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dynamic

I am trying to find a way to derive a class from a generic base class. Say:

```
sealed public class Final : Base<Something>
{

}

public class Base<T> : T
    where T : Anything // <-- Generics do not allow this
{

}
```

In C# this does not seem to be possible.

Is there any other solution to achieve something similar to this?

I found this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913934/create-intance-of-any-c-sharp-class-by-generic-way), but it doesn't seem to solve the issue, or at least I do not understand how it should.

**EDIT:**

The result I'd like to get is to be able to do something like that:

```
Anything[] anything;
//Assign some Instances to anything 

foreach(Final final in anything){
     //do something with final
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance on a constrained generic type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420581/inheritance-on-a-constrained-generic-type-parameter)

Comment: If you want to use it in a `foreach` you need to implement `IEnumerable<Final>`.

Comment: @juharr In my edit above "anything" is an array. So I don't need to do that.

Comment: @juharr just a `MoveNext` and `Current` method would suffice, no need to implement the entire `IEnumerable` interface.

Comment: @NoelWidmer An array of what?

Comment: @Alex True, but it's best practice to implement `IEnumerable<T>` to make it explicit.

Comment: What you want to do isn't logically sound and won't work. You can't derive from a type argument when it's value is established at runtime. How would you know which methods you can for example override? I think you need to reconsider your design such that you derive from whatever type `T` is and then use the `DerivedT` when you instantiate `Base` rather than trying to derive from `T` in `Base<T>`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The result I'd like to get is to be able to do something like that:
>
> ```
>  Anything[] anything;
>  //Assign some Instances to anything 
>
>  foreach(Final final in anything){
>      //do something with final
>  }
> ```

Your `foreach` loop suggests this: `class Anything : Final { … }`.

This obviously turns around the inheritance hierarchy as you planned and named it. (You cannot have cycles in your inheritance relationships).

---

> ```
> public class Base<T> : T where T : Anything { …
> ```

Let me elaborate on this part for a bit. I'll reduce your example even further to just `class Base<T> : T`.

This is not possible, for good reason. Imagine this:

```
class Base<T> : T
{
    public override string Frobble()
    {
        Fiddle();
        return "*" + base.Frobble() + "*";
    }
}

class A
{
    public sealed string Frobble() { … }
}

class B
{
}

class C
{
    public virtual string Frobble() { … }
}

abstract class D
{
    public abstract void Fiddle();
    public virtual string Frobble() { … }
}

class E
{
    public void Fiddle() { … }
    public virtual string Frobble() { … }
}
```

You get all kinds of absurd situations if `class Base<T> : T` were allowed.

- `Base<A>` would be absurd because `Frobble` cannot be overridden in a derived class.
- `Base<B>` would be absurd because you cannot override a method that
  doesn't exist in the base class.
- `Base<C>` doesn't work because there is no `Fiddle` method to call.
- `Base<D>` would not work because you cannot call an abstract method.
- Only `Base<E>` would work.

How would the compiler ever know how to correctly compile `Base<T>` and analyse code that depends on it?

The point is that you cannot derive from a class that is not known at compile-time. `T` is a parameter, i.e. a variable, a placeholder. So `class Base<T> : T` is basically like saying, *"`Base<T>` inherits from some (unknown) class"*. Class inheritance is a type relationship that requires both involved types to be known at compile-time. (Actually, that's not a super-precise statement because you can inherit from a generic type such as `class SpecialList<T> : List<T>`. But at the very least, the derived class has to know what members (methods, properties, etc.) are available in the base class.)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
sealed public class Final : Base<int>{

}

public class Base<T> {

}
```

Comment: Base<T> should now derive from <T>, which is int in this case

Comment: @NoelWidmer That is called generic constraints where you place condition to restrict the type T.

Answer (score 0):

You could only do this if `Final` would be a generic class as well, like so:

```
public sealed class Final<T> : Base<T>
```

Then you can put a type restraint on `T` as either a `class`, to allow only reference types as `T`, or an instance of `Base<T>`, to allow only types that derive from `Base<T>`:

```
public class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context of this question, but I ran into same question with a project where I had to make it possible to extend the base class which is already derived by many others. Like:

```
abstract class Base {}
class FinalA : Base {}
class FinalB : Base {}

// Now create extended base class and expect final classes to be extended as well:
class BetterBase : Base {}
```

The solution was to create common ancestor and connect through properties:

```
abstract class Foundation {}
abstract class Base : Foundation 
{
    Foundation Final { get; }
}
class FinalA : Foundation {}
class FinalB : Foundation {}
class FinalC : Foundation
{
    Foundation Base { get; }
}

// Here's the desired extension:
class BetterBase : Base {}
```

Now BetterBase has connection to final class and if needed, the final classes could have connection with (Better)Base also, as shown in FinalC class.