# How to add the same functionality to different base classes without duplicating code?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have two projects I am currently working on. One is a WPF project, and uses the MvvmLight framework. The other is a Xamarin.Forms project, using FreshMVVM. These two frameworks each have their own implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, used as the base class for all ViewModels in the respective project.

In the WPF Project, I've added a ValidatedViewModel implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo so that I can easily perform validation on user inputs:

```
public abstract class ValidatedViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    protected ValidatedViewModel() : base()
    {
        PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => ValidateProperty(args.PropertyName);
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        return _validationErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName) ? _validationErrors[propertyName] : null;
    }

    public bool HasErrors => _validationErrors.Any();
    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    private void ValidateProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        var value = GetValue(propertyName);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        bool valid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(value,
            new ValidationContext(this, null, null) {MemberName = propertyName}, results);

        if (valid)
        {
            _validationErrors.Remove(propertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            _validationErrors[propertyName] = results.Select(r => r.ErrorMessage);
        }

        RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private object GetValue(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        return propInfo.GetValue(this);
    }
}
```

Since I need validation in my Xamarin.Forms app too, I've had to copy and paste this class, changing only the base class. As a programmer, I hate having to repeat blocks of code like this, so I would like to put this (and some other common functionality like a http client wrapper) into a common assembly which can be used by both projects. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out a way to actually share the ViewModelBase class, as even though the two versions are otherwise identical, they each extend a different base class.

If I could do this:

```
public abstract class ValidatedViewModel<BaseViewModel> : BaseViewModel, INotifyDataErrorInfo where BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

or this:

```
public class WPFViewModelBase : ViewModelBase, ValidatedeViewModel
public class XFViewModelBase : FreshBasePageModel, ValidatedViewModel
```

then this wouldn't be a problem. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, both of these things are impossible.

The only solution that jumps out to me is to have a `ViewModelValidator` class which `WPFViewModelBase` and `XFViewModelBase` each instantiate on construction, and which they forward `INofityDataErrorInfo` calls to, but this seems clunky and doesn't fully eliminate code duplication since I would still have all that identical forwarding code in two different places.

Is there any way I can eliminate all code duplication here?

Comment: Nope, **you can't derive from a type specified by a generic type argument**. I once asked a simmilar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038028/c-sharp-define-base-class-by-t

Comment: Probably a bad suggestion, but what about preprocessor directives? Put `#if XAMARIN` in the base class to derive from the class/interface and never worry about it again. Also, I don't think its  a dupe?

Comment: Your question has been closed. But I created a *gist* for you. It might help: https://gist.github.com/NoelWidmer/785f9f19d30bbd0bd17c86b8d76c77da

Comment: Probably the best approach to this is to create a interface in the external assembly with all of the methods and properties you want shared between these two classes. Then implement the class in the external assembly. implement. Finally make both of your classes that currently share the code implement this new interface and then create an instance of the class you implemented the interface in inside both of your existing classes and have each method of the interface fulfilled by calling in to the  instance methods. This is a form of the decorator pattern.

Comment: Try this code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gK6h9P

Comment: @Enigmativity I've updated the question with a more appropriate title, as it is actually a very different question from the one linked, and the answers in the linked question aren't applicable here. I know that it is not possible to have a generic base class (I say as much already in the question), and want to know what I can do instead in this specific case.

Comment: @Enigmativity that looks like exactly the possible solution I mentioned in the second last paragraph of my question, where I also outline problems with that solution (namely that it still results in quite a bit of duplicated code)

Comment: @NoelWidmer That gist doesn't solve the problem at all. As I mentioned in my question above, the two MVVM frameworks I use already provide their own ViewModelBase classes which implement INotifyPropertyChanged. My ViewModels need both the logic from these base classes and the INotifyDataErrorInfo implementation logic from ValidatedViewModel, and I would like to accomplish this without duplicating any code

Comment: @Katie - I don't think there's any way to avoid the duplication as there isn't multiple inheritance in .NET except for interfaces - hence my suggestion.

Comment: @Katie You might be able to get around this by creating extension methods for `ViewModelBase`. It will however be a bit tricky to use instance fields in there. But even that is possible if you create a dictionary where the key is the instance itself and the value is the instance field you'd like to have. So basically a `Dictionary<ViewModelBase, Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>` for your field which you named `_validationErrors`.

Comment: I don't think the question should be closed because there probably is some weird, dirty and ugly workaround for this issue. But I cannot vote to reopen it.